# Loading duplicate XML attributes using XDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml

I need help loading xml using `XDocument`. The xml holds the data for a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in WPF so each element has the same attributes.

I'm having a newbie problem with how to handle the duplicate attributes Name, image and fileLoc.

I was trying to get something like the code below to work, but as you can see duplicate attributes will not work.

```
public static List<MenuItem> Load(string MyMenuFile)
{       
    var mymenu = XDocument.Load(MyMenuFile).Root.Elements("Menu").Select(
            x => new MenuItem(
            (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                (string)x.Attribute("image"),
                (string)x.Attribute("fileLoc"),
                (string)x.Element("itemlist"),
        (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                (string)x.Attribute("image"),
                (string)x.Attribute("fileLoc"),
                (string)x.Element("item"),
                (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                (string)x.Attribute("image"),
                (string)x.Attribute("fileLoc")));

    return stationfiles.ToList();
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<Menus>
    <Menu id="1"  Name="Level1" image="C:\lvl1.jpg" fileLoc="C:\lvl1.xml">
    </Menu>
    <Menu id="2"  Name="Level2" image="C:\lvl2.jpg" >
        <itemlist Name="Level2" image="C:\lvl2.jpg" fileLoc="C:\lvl2.xml">
        </itemlist>
        <itemlist Name="Level3" image="C:\lvl3.jpg">
            <item Name="First" image="C:\first.jpg" fileLoc="C:\first.xml"></item>
            <item Name="Second" image="C:\second.jpg" fileLoc="C:\second.xml"></item>
            <item Name="Third" image="C:\third.jpg" fileLoc="C:\third.xml"></item>
        </itemlist>
    </Menu>
</Menus>
```

As you can see, different elements but duplicate attributes. Should I have 3 separate classes, but how would I combine them for the `XDocument` load? Any help would be great.

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that both `<Menu>`, `<itemlist>`, and `item` should be a `MenuItem`? And am I correct that an `<itemlist>` could have an `<itemlist>` too? Or does it stop at the `<item>` level?

Comment: I see what you mean, the root is Menus, next element is Menu with attributes, next would be itemlist (optional) with attributes, next would item (also optional) with attributes In the xml above, Menu id=1 has no itemlist or item, Menu id=2 has two itemlist but only the second on has item. An itemlist would only have attributes and item(s).

Answer (score 0):

This assumes those are elements and attributes directly of MenuItem.  What I suspect is that you need read attributes of elements itemslist and items.  Not sure how to do it with a single loop.  You need to loop through the elements and then loop the attribute so THAT element (not the parent element).

Answer (score 0):

You are not being heirarchical in your processing.

I have adjusted your xml, but here is an example of how you should be processing it:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<Menus> 
    <Menu id=""1""  Name=""Level1 - Alpha"" image=""C:\lvl1.jpg"" fileLoc=""C:\lvl1.xml""/> 
    <Menu id=""2""  Name=""Level1 - Beta"" image=""C:\lvl2.jpg"" fileLoc=""C:\lvl1.xml"" > 
        <itemlist Name=""Level2-Gamma"" image=""C:\lvl2.jpg"" fileLoc=""C:\lvl2.xml""/>  
        <itemlist Name=""Level3-Zeta"" image=""C:\lvl3.jpg"" fileLoc=""C:\lvl1.xml""> 
            <item Name=""First"" image=""C:\first.jpg"" fileLoc=""C:\first.xml""></item> 
            <item Name=""Second"" image=""C:\second.jpg"" fileLoc=""C:\second.xml""></item> 
            <item Name=""Third"" image=""C:\third.jpg"" fileLoc=""C:\third.xml""></item> 
        </itemlist> 
    </Menu> 
</Menus>";

var xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var result = 

xd.Descendants("Menu")
  .Select (l1 => new 
  {
   Name     = l1.Attribute("Name").Value, 
   Image    = l1.Attribute("image").Value, 
   File     = l1.Attribute("fileLoc"),
   Children = l1.Descendants("itemlist")
                  .Select (l2 => new {
                                Name     = l2.Attribute("Name").Value, 
                                Image    = l2.Attribute("image").Value, 
                                File     = l2.Attribute("fileLoc"),
                                Children = l2.Descendants("item")
                                                .Select (l3 => new {
                                                        Name  = l3.Attribute("Name").Value, 
                                                        Image = l3.Attribute("image").Value, 
                                                        File  = l3.Attribute("fileLoc")
                                                                    })
                  })

});

Console.WriteLine (result );
```

Here is the result as found from linqpad:

[image]

See how the data parses out, that is how you need to work with it to get it into the menu structure. There are no duplicate attributes. :-)

HTH